# One onclick not firing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a simple script that when you click the text it will bring up a pop up window with a youtube video.  I have it working where it loads on the page hidden and then when I click the text it shows.  My problem is that I can't seem to the window to close when I click X.  My suspicion is that since the div is hidden, it can't register the onclick, but if this is the case how do I register it?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .pop-up{
            display: none;
            width: 460px;
            height: 385px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            position:absolute;
            top: 300px;
            left: 300px;
        }
        .inner-pop-up{
            display: block;
            width: 420px;
            height: 345px;
            background-color: #333;
            position:relative;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
        }
        p{
            margin: 0;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            float: right;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div").click(function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "block");
      });
      $("p").click(function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "none");
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black;">
    <div style="color: white;">
        Click Me
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up">
        <p>X</p>
        <div class="inner-pop-up">
            <embed
                width="420" height="345"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            </embed>
        </div>
    <div>
</bodY>
```

Additionally I'm wondering if it is possible to darken out everything outside of the white frame as in dim it down so the white frame takes focus and then when I click anywhere outside of the frame, this frame will close.

Comment: where is the Pop-Up function in your Javascript?

Comment: There is no JS, its just JQuery .click events.  The onclick I had I removed, was old code not being used.

Comment: you specify in your jQuery `$("div")` all divs, can't you be more specific to only the `div` that needs the `click` event? or do you want it on all divs?

Comment: you can try Telerik pop-up windows functionality of dimming, freezing background page

Comment: as this is just an example to see if I can make it all work it didn't matter to me which div I clicked on.  I'll modify the code so that it calls only on one div.

Comment: @VDesign that actually fixed the problem.  Thank you.  Now I'm wondering about my other question, how can I dim a page behind this popped up div.  I would rather not plugins or scripts written by others but try to understand how this is actually done and write the whole code myself.

Comment: I will pose this as a new question as they are two things and my original problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

@VDesign was correct, the targeting of div in your event is not allowing the click of the P later on.

By setting a class and targeting it correctly the P works as a close.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.clickme").click(function(){
    $('.pop-up').css("display", "block");
  });
  $("p").click(function(){
    $('.pop-up').css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vx9t/

Answer (score -1):

here is js fiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshok/Uj9c2/

please include jquery migrate file also to use live function, you can check in fiddle

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div").click(function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "block");
      });
      $("#close").live('click',function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "none");
      });
    });
```

Comment: Or you could use `.on()` instead of the years-ago deprecated `.live()` and not need the migrate script. Or not use event delegation at all because it's not even needed.

Answer (score -1):

it's working . as you didn't write your pop up function in javascript. remove that.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/N9qCu/)

```
<div class="h" style="color: white;" >
        Click Me
    </div>
    <div class="pop-up">
        <p>X</p>
        <div class="inner-pop-up">
            <embed
                width="420" height="345"
                src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            </embed>
        </div>
    <div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".h").click(function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "block");
      });
      $("p").on('click',function(){
        $('.pop-up').css("display", "none");
      });
    });
```